# My stored procedure with PHP and Postman SQL Server saves me NULL

Tags: php, sql-server

I am having problems when executing my stored procedure that performs an insert to 2 tables, I have tried different methods and it always registers 1 row but with Null parameters.

**Method 1**

```php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$host,1433; Database=$dbname", $user, $password);
    if ($dbh === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($json);

    $sql = "execute AUT_APPREGISTRATE @NOMBRE=?, @APELLIDO_P=?, @APELLIDO_M=?, @NDOCUMENTO=?, @CORREO=?, @ESTADO=?, @NICK=?, @CLAVE=?, @IDPERFIL=?, @NFOTOCHEK=? ";

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $NOMBRE);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $APELLIDO_P);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $APELLIDO_M);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $NDOCUMENTO);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $CORREO);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $ESTADO);
    $stmt->bindParam(7, $NICK);
    $stmt->bindParam(8, $CLAVE);
    $stmt->bindParam(9, $IDPERFIL);
    $stmt->bindParam(10, $NFOTOCHEK);

    if ($stmt === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $res = $stmt->execute();

    if (!$res) $mensaje = "ERROR";
    else $mensaje = "GRABADO";


    //sqlsrv_free_stmt($res);
   // sqlsrv_close($dbh);

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $response = array("resultado" => $mensaje);
    echo json_encode($response);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    exit;
}
```

**Method 2**

```php
$sql = "exec AUT_APPREGISTRATE :NOMBRE, :APELLIDO_P, :APELLIDO_M, :NDOCUMENTO, :CORREO, :ESTADO, :NICK, :CLAVE, :IDPERFIL, :NFOTOCHEK ";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':NOMBRE', $NOMBRE);
//(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(':APELLIDO_P', $APELLIDO_P);
$stmt->bindParam(':APELLIDO_M', $APELLIDO_M);
$stmt->bindParam(':NDOCUMENTO', $NDOCUMENTO);
$stmt->bindParam(':CORREO', $CORREO);
$stmt->bindParam(':ESTADO', $ESTADO);
$stmt->bindParam(':NICK', $NICK);
$stmt->bindParam(':CLAVE', $CLAVE);
$stmt->bindParam(':IDPERFIL', $IDPERFIL);
$stmt->bindParam(':NFOTOCHEK', $NFOTOCHEK);

$res = $stmt->execute();

//$res=$dbh->query($stmt);
if (!$res) $mensaje = "ERROR";
else $mensaje = "GRABADO";
```

when I execute by POSTMAN it gives me the success message, but when verifying in the table it only inserts 1 row with Null values, when I execute for 2 times it no longer registers me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `sqlsrv_*`-functions when you're using PDO?

Comment: well, comment on those 2 final lines, the same is the result.

Comment: Where do these variables come from? They don't magically become PHP variables direct from the query string, you need to use `$_GET`

Comment: There are several issues here with your code vs your Postman settings. 1. If you want to send `x-www-form-urlencoded` data (which are sent in the body of the request), you should use POST. GET requests doesn't support sending data in the body. 2. In your code, you're trying to fetch the data using `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');` despite the fact that you're not _sending_ any data as JSON. If you want to do that, you will still need to make it a POST request (since the JSON data also will be sent in the body). You're currently not sending _anything_ to the server.